# Cannot set up React environment in macOS Ventura

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, terminal, macos-ventura

I was trying to set up react environment on my m1 mac for the first time.
As soon as I tried to run the command "npx create-react-app my-app", I am getting error

```
"npm ERR! path /Users/abd/Desktop/React/my-app/node_modules/core-js-pure
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
```

I tried to update my node as well as npm but nothing worked so far.
The logs show following errors -

```
6831 verbose stack Error: command failed
6831 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:63:27)
6831 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
6831 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
6831 verbose stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
6831 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
6831 verbose stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:320:12)
6832 verbose pkgid core-js-pure@3.27.2
6833 verbose cwd /Users/abd/Desktop/React/my-app
6834 verbose Darwin 22.2.0
6835 verbose node v18.13.0
6836 verbose npm  v8.19.3
6837 error path /Users/abd/Desktop/React/my-app/node_modules/core-js-pure
6838 error command failed
6839 error signal SIGKILL
6840 error command sh -c -- node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
6841 verbose exit 1
6842 timing npm Completed in 147361ms
6843 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1674722956943
6844 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1674723102249
6845 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1674723102250
6846 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1674723102250
6847 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1674723102271
6848 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/core-js 1674723102271
6849 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/core-js-pure 1674723102275
6850 verbose code 1
```

Comment: please do format your error

Comment: Done with the formatting.

Comment: Getting a SIGKILL is a bit weird – do you have enough free memory?

Comment: Yes, more than 94GB available.